# What is the difference between TEST, TEST_F and TEST_P?

Tags: googletest, googlemock

I have researched a lot about gtest/gmock but none of them gave me the right answer. I'm new to C++ so any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

All documentation is covered in the [official github repo](https://github.com/google/googletest). The [primer documentation](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/primer.md) also covers a lot of information regarding the test macros. You could use the following summary and the examples linked to choose what you want to use.

`TEST()` is useful when you want to write unit tests for static or global functions or simple classes. [Example test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/565f1b848215b77c3732bca345fe76a0431d8b34/googletest/test/googletest-port-test.cc#L54)

`TEST_F()` is useful when you need access to objects and subroutines in the unit test. [Example test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/e8a82dc7ede61c4af3b9d75aa0e953b8cecfc8bb/googletest/test/gtest_unittest.cc#L102)

`TEST_P()` is useful when you want to write tests with a parameter. Instead of writing multiple tests with different values of the parameter, you can write one test using `TEST_P()` which uses `GetParam()` and can be instantiated using `INSTANTIATE_TEST_SUITE_P()`. [Example test](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/eafd2a91bb0c4fd626aae63ae852812fbd4999f2/googletest/test/googletest-param-test-test.cc#L679)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's really help the community.

Comment: updated link to googletest primer: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/primer.md

Comment: [Here](http://google.github.io/googletest/primer.html) you can read the "Googletest Primer" in the official documentation, which is better formatted.

Comment: [Advanced googletest Topics | GoogleTest](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html) introduces `TEST_P()` .

Answer (score 8):

I think my answer to this is:

In C++ testing frameworks, TEST, TEST_F, and TEST_P are macros used to define test cases. Here's the difference between them:

TEST: This macro is used to define a standalone test case. It is typically used when you have a single test case that does not need any setup or teardown code.

TEST_F: This macro is used to define a test case that needs to set up some fixtures before running the test and tear them down afterward. A fixture is a set of data or objects that you want to use across multiple tests. TEST_F is short for "test fixture".

TEST_P: This macro is used to define a test case that takes parameters. It is typically used when you want to run the same test with different inputs. The TEST_P macro is followed by a set of parameters that are passed to the test case.

In summary, TEST is for standalone test cases, TEST_F is for test cases with fixtures, and TEST_P is for test cases with parameters. The choice of which macro to use depends on the specific testing needs and requirements of your project.